# unable to call jsp file under the folder using getRequestDispatcher forword

Tags: java, servlets

I have a `JSP` file under the folder name `adminlogin`. I am using `getRequestDispatcher` and `forword` to call the `jsp` file but I am unable to get the request and it is showing me `404` error.

The url link is `http://localhost:8084/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp`

Following is my code,

```
String opt = menu_display.print_opt();
request.setAttribute("menu_display", opt);
request.getRequestDispatcher("adminlogin/menu.jsp?p=1").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to adminlogin should have a "/" since it is relative to the context path of your application:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/adminlogin/menu.jsp?p=1").forward(request, response);
```

If you do not have a "/"  the servlet engine is looking for it relative to the **current** url.

Comment: I have tried using "/adminlogin/menu.jsp?p=1" but it still gives me 404 error

Comment: What is the url on the browser just before you try the forward?  And what is the physical path of the menu.jsp relative to the root of your java web application?

Comment: Url on the browser is http://localhost:8084/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp and the physical path of **menu.jsp** is under webpages I have created a folder name **adminlogin** which has the file name menu.jsp. I and trying to  foreword the request using servlet .

Comment: The URL cannot be http://localhost:8084/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp because that is where you are trying to forward to. What I am  asking is the url "before you try the forward" , ie the URL of the servlet

Comment: I have updated the answer , the complete url should be "/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp?p=1" since "demo" is the context path of your web app

Comment: sir I have tried but still giving me 404 error  Broswer message : **message** /demo/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp . **description** The requested resource (/demo/demo/adminlogin/menu.jsp) is not available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89501/discussion-between-chrisl08-and-nikalldway).